# What did the English call alcohol before they had the word alcohol?

Tags: etymology

Presumably the English knew that there existed a compound common to fermented or distilled liquids that caused intoxication, but before they had the word alcohol, what did they call this chemical compound?

Comment: It appears that you're asking about the scientific term, not the name for "booze", although I'm not quite sure. I tried to address both in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an interesting article on the [etymology of alcohol.](http://heliologue.com/2010/03/17/wednesday%E2%80%99s-word-alcohol/) It claims that in Middle English, they callled intoxicants *licur* (which we know as liquor) - which means, well, liquid - and *bouse* (which we know as booze), which was the word for "beer", and applied in the general to drink, especially in verb form (bousen).

Comment: It is a very interesting article, a pity you didn't post more details in your answer.

Comment: The article mentions 'aqua vitae' as a term for spirits. 'Strong waters' is another old term for alcoholic drink.

Answer (score 3):

> **Spirits:**
>
> [An alcoholic beverage, especially distilled liquor; ***Also a scientific term: An alcohol solution of an essential or volatile substance.***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/spirits)
>
> **[Origin: 1200–50; Middle English](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/spirits?&path=/)**  (noun) < Latin spīritus  orig., a breathing, equivalent to spīri-,  combining form representing
>   spīrāre  to breathe + -tus  suffix of v. action
>
> **Ether** is another term to consider, since the language of your question seems to lean in the scientific direction:
>
> [An organic compound in which two hydrocarbon groups are linked by an
>   oxygen atom, having the general structure ROR', where R and R' are the
>   two hydrocarbon groups. At room temperature, **ethers are
>   pleasant-smelling liquids resembling alcohols but less dense and less
>   soluble in water**.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ether?s=t)
>
> [**Origin: 1350–1400; Middle English**  < Latin aethēr  the upper
>   air, pure air, ether < Greek aithḗr,  akin to aíthein  to glow, burn,
>   Old English ād  funeral pyre, Latin aestus  heat](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ether?s=t)

In older scientific literature, ***ether*** had many different meanings and usages. See: [The Composition and Structure of Ether:](http://classes.yale.edu/chem225/studyaids/history/ether/ether.html)

> **The preparation of alcohol** (spirit of wine, vinic alcohol, ethanol,
>   ethyl alcohol) by fermentation dates to antiquity. **Closely related to
>    alcohol  -- both through history and chemistry** -- is **ether** (ethyl
>   ether, diethyl ether) **a compound obtained from alcohol** by the action
>   of oil of vitriol (sulfuric acid).

Or (if you're talking about liquor):

> **Drink:**
>
> [liquor; alcohol.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Drink?s=t)

which is even earlier:

> [**Origin:before 900; Middle English** drinken, Old English drincan; 
>   cognate with Dutch drinken, German trinken, Gothic drinkan, Old Norse
>   drekka](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Drink?s=t)

Alcohol is a later addition to the language:

> **Alcohol:**
>
> [**Origin: 1535–45;  < Neo-Latin**  < Medieval Latin  < Arabic al-ku?l 
>   the powdered antimony, the distillate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/alcohol)

Comment: Superficially this answer looks good, lots of quotes and references. However, all quotes but one are from an online dictionary, and the one that isn't refers to ether which the question is not about. Also, too much blue again. +1 for effort -1 for criticism net 0.

Comment: I suggest you remove the bit about ether. Anyone with basic knowledge in organic chemistry would tell you that it is not alcohol. Yes they are related and have almost similar structures, but they are completely distinct classes of compounds.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel - it is not an online dictionary. It is a dictionary online. Check out references on the pages...  And please read **carefully** my answer and references - they **do** address the question. (I don't see any blue at all...)

Comment: @LouisRhys - not sure how widespread the knowledge of organic chemistry was in 15th/16th century England, the period in question. Read carefully my answer and references.

Comment: good point.. They didn't know about organic chemistry, which means that they wouldn't know that ether had a "general structure ROR'", related to alcohol. It's more reason to disassociate alcohol and ether.

Comment: @LouisRhys - clever, but perhaps too technical: Follow these links: [Exilirs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aether_%28classical_element%29#Quintessence.2C_as_used_in_alchemy)- look for elixirs there which links to: [An elixir is a hydro-alcoholic solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elixirs#Composition). In the period we're talking about, "ether" had a very different meaning - it meant a lot of things, especially something flammable that evaporated quickly.

Comment: This SE has a different color scheme, they format hyperlinked text red instead of blue.

Answer (score 0):

***mead***

> 1. an alcoholic liquor made by fermenting honey and water.
> 2. any of various nonalcoholic beverages.
>
> Origin of *mead*
>
> Before 900; Middle English *mede*, Old English *medu*, *meodu*; cognate with Dutch *mee*, German *Met*, Old Norse *mjǫthr mead*, Sanskrit *madhu honey*, Greek *méthy wine*

[***rum***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rum%2Calcohol&year_start=1500&year_end=1800&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crum%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Calcohol%3B%2Cc0)

> 1. an alcoholic liquor or spirit distilled from molasses or some other fermented sugar-cane product.
> 2. [*North American*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/rum) alcoholic drink in general; intoxicating liquor: *He warned against the [**demon rum**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=demon+rum%2Cdemon+alcohol%2Cdemon+liquor%2Cdemon+spirits&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdemon%20rum%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdemon%20alcohol%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdemon%20liquor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdemon%20spirits%3B%2Cc0).*
>
> Origin of *rum*: 1645-55; perhaps short for obsolete [***rumbullion***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rumbullion), *rumbustion*, of obscure origin

[Random House](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rum?s=t)